# why this code is crashing on cvtColor?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code:

```
void * imageBuffer = reinterpret_cast<void *>(exposureBuffer + imageHeader->imgoffset);
cv::Mat imageRaw(imageHeader->height, imageHeader->width, CV_8UC1, imageBuffer);
cv::Mat imageColour;
cv::cvtColor(imageRaw, imageColour, cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGR);
```

when I run this and stops debugger on this line:

```
cv::Mat imageColour;
```

I can see that imageRaw has a valid image in it (I can see the image in image view and it is a valid image.)

but then the application crashes on this line:

```
 cv::cvtColor(imageRaw, imageColour, cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGR);
```

and it seems that a mat file was created but not enough memory allocated for it.

The error message is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF7503F992B in test_PictureProcessing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000023.
```

I am using OpenCv 3. I have similar code which runs successfully on openCV 2.

## Edit1

I changed the code to this one to make sure that imagebuffer is a valid buffer and the fact that I am not initializing imageColour is not the problem:

```
void *imageBuffer = new char[imageHeader->height* imageHeader->width];
cv::Mat imageRaw(imageHeader->height, imageHeader->width, CV_8UC1, imageBuffer);
cv::Mat imageColour = imageRaw.clone();
```

but I am still getting error on this line:

```
cv::Mat imageColour = imageRaw.clone();
```

## Edit 2

This is also crashing!

```
cv::Mat imageRaw(imageHeader->height, imageHeader->width, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat imageColour = imageRaw.clone();
```

Why this simple code crashing?

Comment: Is `imageBuffer` null (or very small)? What about `exposureBuffer`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenCV, but I'd guess, that you have to initialize imageColor, before it can be used as an output parameter in cvtColor.

Comment: @Mat No they are large enough for image. Also When I use image view in visual studio, I can see raw image so buffer is valid and big enough for this. But I am going to do a test to make sure that it is big enough.

Comment: What are the actual values of `imageHeader->height` and `imageHeader->width`?  Also, seeing a "picture" doesn't prove that you allocated enough space.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie they are 2746 and 3664 respectively.

Comment: This is really strange. Are you compiling in debug mode or with any optimizations? How did you determine, that it is this line that crashes? Have you tried a different compiler?

Comment: @MikeMB, I am using the debug mode in visual studio 2013 and opencv 3.0.0. I know that it works on openCv 2.x

Comment: openCV 3.0.0 is still beta, so maybe its a bug in opencv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem which is very strange!

I forgot to include opencv.hpp to my source file after adding it, it worked perfectly.

It is strange as I did not get any compile error, but I got run time error.

If you see your openCV behave strangely, make sure that you included opencv.hpp to your source code. it may help you to solve your problem! Not all problems are coming from missing this header as CroCo mentioned.

Comment: "If you see your openCV behave strangely, make sure that you included opencv.hpp to your source code." not all problems are coming from missing this header.

Comment: @CroCo Updated answer to highlight this.